# Example showing nontrivial supremum in limit

Tags: real-analysis, limits

What are some good examples of $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ that satisfy

$\limsup_{x \to \infty} \left|\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}\right|> 0$

but not

$\lim_{x \to \infty} \left|\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}\right|> 0$

And what about

$\liminf_{x \to \infty} \left|\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}\right| > 0$

but not

$\lim_{x \to \infty} \left|\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}\right| > 0$

?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand here: we know that the limit exists iff it equals the common value of lim sup **and** the lim inf. Perhaps you meant the other direction?

Comment: Corrected.  Does it now make sense?

Comment: Consider $f(x)=\sin x$ and $g(x)=1$ for the first case and consider $f(x)=\sin x+2$ and $g(x)=1$ for the second one.

Comment: @qazwsx, it is fine now.

Comment: @mfl Is there any non-periodic ones?

Comment: Yes. $f(x)=1/x+\sin x$ and $g(x)=1.$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have that

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\left|\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}\right|=L\iff \overline{\lim_{x\to\infty}}\left|\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}\right|=L=\underline{\lim_{x\to\infty}}\left|\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}\right| $$

so the counterexample you're searching doesn't exist.

Now, for the edited question we can take

$$\;f(x):=\sin x\;,\;\;g(x)=1\;\implies \overline{\lim_{x\to\infty}}\left|\frac{\sin x}{1}\right|=\overline{\lim_{x\to\infty}}|\sin x|=1$$

But the limit doesn't exist, since for example

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}|\sin(n\pi)|=0$$